# Reuse of maven uber.pom in gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

In my company we use maven as default build tool. We also have "uber.pom" where are defined default versions of some common libraries in dependencyManagement section ( to ensure consistency across our projects ). All our projects reference this pom as parent.pom. In one of our project, we decided to use gradle. I'm wondering if there is some way we can reference "uber.pom" so we don't have to define same version properties again for gradle. I don't want to end up maintaining uber.pom and gradle.properties in sync. 
I assume I can write some plugin that would parse uber.pom and get versions and then set it to my gradle project, but I want to be sure there is no some better, straightforward way of achieving that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle doesn't currently have built-in support for getting build information from Uber POMs. You'll have to write your own plugin.